# Django submit file form won't save to models through front-end

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

So the goal is to get the user to upload images inside the application, and for the images to be displayed on the screen.

The problem is that the forms will not save to the models I made. I am following Django Central https://djangocentral.com/uploading-images-with-django/ for guidance for uploading my images.

What I have at the moment is where the user can type inside the form for their caption and where the user can select a file for their image, but nothing happens when they click the upload button. All that happens, is that it redirects me to the homepage for some reason, but I can fix that later. The only way for the images to be displayed on the website is if I manually go into the admin panel and upload the image there. If anyone could help I would much appreciate it.

view.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = User_Profile_Form(data = request.POST, files = request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            obj = form.instance
            return render(request, "main/profile.html", {"obj":obj})
    else:
        form = User_Profile_Form()
    img = User_Profile.objects.all()
    return render(request,"main/profile.html", {"img":img, "form":form})
```

models.py

```
class User_Profile(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "img/%y", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import User_Profile

class User_Profile_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User_Profile
        fields = ("caption", "image")
```

profile.html

```
                <div class="container">
                    <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form.as_p}}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Upload</button>
                    </form>

                    {% if obj %}
                    <h3>Succesfully uploaded : {{img_obj.caption}}</h3>
                    <img src="{{ obj.image.url}}" alt="image" class="img-thumbnail" >
                    {% endif %}
                    <hr>


                    {% for x in img %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}<div class="row ">{% endif %}
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12" >
                    <div class="text-center mt-2">
                        <img src="{{x.image.url}}" height="70%" width="70%" class="img-thumbnail" alt="...">
                        <h2 class="text-center" >{{x.caption}}</h2></div>
                        </div>
                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                    </div>
                    <div class=row>{% endif %}
                        {% if forloop.last %}</div>{% endif %}

                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the template? Also does `form.is_valid()` return `True`?

Comment: I just added my html code, and is there way I can see if it returns True, like if I used the console? @bdbd

Comment: I think print statements would be enough if you are running this locally. You can see the output from your terminal or IDE

Comment: I forgot you could that though the terminal loll, thank you man, work smarter not harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the template change the action:
from:

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

To:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

`.` redirects you to the home page.

in `views.py`

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = User_Profile_Form(data = request.POST, files = request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            obj = form.instance
            return render(request, "main/profile.html", {"obj":obj, "form":form})
    else:
        form = User_Profile_Form()
    img = User_Profile.objects.all()
    return render(request,"main/profile.html", {"img":img, "form":form})
```

Comment: Beat me to it ;) if it doesn't work try to set the action to the url of `profile` @Anthony Humphreys

Comment: @bdbd The code worked, but I wanted to take it one step further, so that I could implement other functions easier in the future. With the views function above "profile", that function renders the page and uploads the image and I wanted to have two separate functions where one renders the page and the other uploads the image, but when I do that the form disappears. So I tried making the image_upload function have a url so I could call it in the action, like you said above. But that didn't work, any tips?

Comment: That sounds like it should be a new question. Otherwise, can you update your question with the current code you have? Hard to know what `didn't work` means. What is the actual output and what do you expect?

Comment: @AnthonyHumphreys the form will not disappear if you pass the form after saving it. use this `return render(request, "main/profile.html", {"obj":obj , "form":form})`

Comment: @Jafoor Wait I am little confused I tried that on all three of my functions in the view.py and it didn't work. Where exactly do I write return render function again. Sorry.

Comment: how will i say without knowing what you have changed? I am updating my solution just do like that.

Comment: I asked a new question so it would be easier to see the changes, and to keep this question still relevant. Also, is it bad to ask a lot of questions on Stack overflow, I really don't mean to be a leach.

Answer (score 1):

i know what you want to do, i did it on my project, here is my code, edited for your self

views.py

```
pimageupdate = ProfileImageUpdate(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if pimageupdate.is_valid():
            pimageupdate.save()
```

should i note that pimageupdate is getting the form from forms.py

and you should add user in your {{}} code like this

```
{{user.userprofile.default_profile_picture}}
```

change "post" in your form tag to "POST"

hope this work, let me know if you tried them